# Replacing multiple words in a string from a file

Tags: python, replace, format, translate

For this project we were given a text file that looked like this:

```
r:are
y:why
u:you
ttyl:talk to you later
l8:late
brb:be right back
lol:laughing out loud
bbl:be back later
...etc...
```

The idea is to make a program to translate an sentence from text speech to normal, I used the `.replace` method, but it is giving me results I don't understand.

I am on Windows 8 using Python version 3.4.0

This is my current code:

```
def main():
    sentence={}
    sentence=input("enter a sentence to translate\n")
    slang_file = open('slang.txt', 'r')
    for line in slang_file:
        slangword,unslang=line.split(":")
        if slangword in sentence:
            sentence = sentence.replace(slangword, unslang)
    print(sentence)
main()
```

Here is my output:

```
>>> 
enter a sentence to translate
here r some problems. wuts wrong
heare
e are
some pare
oblems. wyou
ts ware
ong
>>>
```

Any help or pointers would be nice.

Comment: One problem is that you're not trimming newlines from the slang phrases.  Another problem is that you are matching single letters that are a part of a word, not the whole word.

Answer (score 0):

The idea is to detect a whole word..
The problem with your current code is you are replacing even letters in a word; which is something you don't wanna do..
Since I am not an expert in python, you might improve the code..

```
def main():
    sentence={}
    sentence=input("enter a sentence to translate\n")
    slang_file = open('slang.txt', 'r')
    for line in slang_file:
        slangword,unslang=line.strip().split(":")
        if slangword in sentence.split(" "):
            sentence = sentence.replace(slangword+" ", unslang+" ")
            sentence = sentence.replace(" "+slangword, " "+unslang)
    print(sentence)
main()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
deslang = {}
with open('slang.txt', 'r') as f:
    for line in f:
        slang, unslang = line.strip().split(':')
        deslang[slang] = unslang

sentence = input('Enter sentence to translate: ')
for word in deslang:
    sentence.replace(word, deslang[word])
print(sentence)

Enter sentence to translate: y r u l8?
why are you late?
```

Answer (score 0):

The basic problem is:

```
1. you should split the stencence before replace operation, otherwise it may
use part of stencence which not you want.
2. str.replace will replace all word in str that satisfy your condition
```

For example, when do 'r' replacement in your code, the original word :

```
here r some problem.
```

will replace all 'r' inside it, and changed to:

```
heare are some pareoblem
```

The solution is simple, like below:

```
def main():
    sentence=input("enter a sentence to translate\n")
    slang_dict = {}
    slang_file = open('slang.txt', 'r')

    for line in slang_file:
        slangword,unslang=line.split(":")
        slang_dict[slangword] = unslang

    result = ""
    for item in sentence.split():
        if item in slang_dict.keys():
            result += slang_dict[item]
        else:
            result += item
        result += " "
    print result
```

And some minor problems:

```
1. don't define stencence with {} as that means stencence is dict,
while it's actuall string.
2. use local dict to store mapping in slang.txt, as it may be repeated used 
and it's waste of time to read file each time
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are doing any type of natural language processing, it is useful to learn the re module early on:

```
import re

def main():
    slang_file = [line.strip().split(":") for line in open("slang.txt")]
    slang = {k:v for k, v in slang_file}
    sentence = input("enter a sentence to translate\n")
    print(
        re.sub(r"\w+", lambda m: slang.get(m.group(0), m.group(0)), sentence)
    )

main()
```

Here explained in detail:

```
def main():
    # open the input file
    slang_file = open("slang.txt")

    # using a normal list instead of list comprehension
    tmp_list = []

    # the built-in iter method will give you each line
    for line in slang_file:

        # strip the line of linefeeds, carriage returns and spaces
        line = line.strip()

        # split the line in two parts and save to our list
        tmp_list.append(line.split(":"))

    # add each item to a dictionary
    slang = {}

    # key is what you want to find
    # value is what you want to replace it with
    for key, value in tmp_list:
        slang[key] = value

    # get the sentence to translate
    sentence = input("enter a sentence to translate\n")

    #in regular expression \w matches any letter or number
    #\w+ matches any consecutive combination of letters or numbers

    # the second argument is normally a replace statement
    # however this is where the lambda function is helpful
    # m takes the match object for \w+
    # the matched text is retrieved by m.group()
    # which we then use as a key for the slang dictionary to get the replacement
    # the second m.group() is there to be returned when the key is not in slang
    print(
        re.sub(r"\w+", lambda m: slang.get(m.group(), m.group()), sentence)
    )
```